# Django with mysql - get error loading mysqldb module

Tags: python, mysql, django

(windows server 2008 r2) python 34,

I changed settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

1) I run the command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

i get an error:
error loading mysqldb module django.core.exception error loading mysqldb

2) I run the command:

```
 pip install mysql -python
```

get "failed building wheel for mysql-python microsoft visulal c++ 2010 is required unable to find vcvarsall.bat

3)  visual c++ 2010 was installed

I have in system variable path to:C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34;

Furthermore i success to run commands from python to mysql (create\read\write table)

what else can i do in order the command  python manage.py migrate will work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysqlclient , it supports Python3 .You can read about it in django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers).

Answer (score 0):

If 
`pip install MySQL-python`
 is failing, you can try
 `easy_install MySQL-python`.

Also install this: `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

Comment: same error: error: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Un
unble to find vcvarsall.bat).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by running the following command:
 pip install mysqlclient